# Do shield's AP stack with the player's armour AP?

Tags: combat, rogue-trader, armor

The rulebook says the shield applies its AP to the arm. Do these stack with the player's armour on said location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accoring to the rulebook, **armor on same location does not stack**. No exceptions can be seen on the shields.

But maybe your GM can be persuaded to go around this with a house rule, knowing that if you carry a shield and armor you suddently become really hard to kill (which i could imagine being your plan.)

Comment: It's actually one of my players who told me it does stack... the "not stacking" rule talks about "worn" armour (like wearing a chain mail over a leather vest). Because shields aren't exactly that, it's a bit confusing wether we should stack armor or not.

Comment: As said in my other answer, I can only recite what rules as written say. I hear your argument, and it will not be the first time in history that the gamemakers are not completely clear in their formulation. I looked through the erretas, but could find nothing. I would leave it up to the GameMaster of your campaign, or put it to a vote in your group.